# Как из массива выбрать все ключи с определенным значением и записать в новый?

Tags: php, массивы

```
Array ( [лекция] => on [лаба] => on [практика] => on [контрольныя] => on [дз] => on [летучка] => on [премия_лектора] => on [курсовая] => on [премия_курсовой] => off [экзамен_или_зачет] => Зачет [конспект] => off )
```

> дан массив-необходимо записать ключи
>   старого массива где  есть
>   значение 'on' или 'экзамен' или
>   'зачет' в новый массив где ключи
>   старого станут значением

или хотя бы только со значением on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давно не работал с PHP, но по моему так:

```
var $aArrayNew = array();
foreach ($aArrayOld as $key=>$val)
        {
        if ($val == "on" || $val == "экзамен" || $val == "зачёт")
            $aArrayNew[] = $key;
        }
```

Comment: 30 секунд) Опоздал)

Answer (score 0):

Просто перебираете массив и все.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) //Где $array - исходный массив;
{
if ($val == "on") //Или 'экзамен', или 'зачет' :D;
{
$new_array[] = $key; //Записывем в новый массив ключ старого как значение;
}
}
```

Кажется,так, если правильно все понял.